# How can I get two sequences of "footnotes" in one LaTeX document, one as footnotes, the other as endnotes?

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I want to have two distinct sequences of "footnotes" in a single text, one as footnotes, the other as endnotes. Can this be accomplished in LaTeX? If so, how?

In case it isn't clear what I mean, here's the use-case. Sometimes one has two distinct classes of material for notes:

1. Notes that extend or amplify the discussion of the text and that most readers would want to (or ought to) read, and
2. Notes containing only scholarly apparatus or points of relevance to only the most specialized of specialists.

It is especially helpful if these two classes of notes can have a different sequence of references and if those of type (1) are footnotes while those of type (2) are endnotes. 
(This use can be seen in, for instance, Martha Nusbaum's [The fragility of Goodness](http://books.google.ca/books?id=GCKqZkyzFO0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor%3a%22Martha+Craven+Nussbaum%22&hl=en&ei=6g9OTM7hNKOQnwe78cXYCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

I would love to be able to achieve this in LaTeX, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you looked at the `endnotes` package? It does precisely what you want, with the option to collect both footnotes and endnotes into one.

http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/endnotes.html

Comment: Sweet!

Here's an example:

\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{endnotes}

%To make the sequences differ.
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}
    
I want this.\footnote{This is of general importance.}

And I want this.\endnote{This is of import to specialists.}

\clearpage

\theendnotes

    
\end{document}

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using `\footnote` for Case 1 and `\cite` for Case 2.  While `\cite` is designed to point to elements of the References list, there is no reason that your references must contain bibliographic data exclusively.

Comment: This is how certain academic disciplines normally go about things.