# change footnotes to endnotes, but allow some old footnotes

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

My question is similar to [How can I get two sequences of "footnotes" in one LaTeX document, one as footnotes, the other as endnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-can-i-get-two-sequences-of-footnotes-in-one-latex-document-one-as-footnot?rq=1) and also to  [Is there a way to move all footnotes to the end of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56145/is-there-a-way-to-move-all-footnotes-to-the-end-of-the-document)

I have a book project that uses `\footnote{}` for **all notes**, but it is proposed to change all such notes that are just references or scholarly notes to endnotes, while also leaving notes that amplify the discussion as footnotes.  I estimate that ~ 90% of notes will become endnotes.

- change in the text those that should remain footnotes to use a new command `\FN{}`
- redefine `\footnote{}` to `\pagenote{}` using the `pagenote` package (this seems more capable than `endnotes`).

But I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  What I'm thinking is to use the following:

```
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\let\footnote\pagenote
\newcommand{\FN}[1]{\oldfootnote{#1}}
```

Will this work? That is,

- can one actually have footnotes **and** endnotes in the same document?
- will my method of defining `\FN{}` in terms of a saved `\oldfootnote` work?

**Edit**:
What I proposed above **does work**, at least partially.  That is, notes coded as `\FN{}` do appear as footnotes in the text, while all others, coded as `\footnote{}` are translated to endnotes, and appear in a final **Notes** `\chapter*{Notes}`.
However, they are all shown in the text with sequential superscript numbers.

If I am to make this work, I need to distinguish the footnotes from the endnotes in the text, say, by using superscript letters for the footnote symbols.  I tried reordering the commands and re-defining the footnote symbol as follows, but this doesn't make the `\FN{}`s appear as superscript letters.

```
\usepackage{pagenote}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\newcommand{\FN}[1]{\oldfootnote{#1}}
\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@alph
\makeatother

\makepagenote
\let\footnote\pagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
```

Comment: I'd find/replace the existing footnote commands (easy in any respectable editor) rather than unnecessarily redefining the command

Comment: i've seen `enotez` used in a book that had both (a lot of) endnotes and (just a few) footnotes.  (unfortunately, i haven't got time right now to dig up the archive.)

Comment: @ChrisH There would be far too many footnotes to change to endnotes.  My idea, if it can be made to work, requires changing only a small number to `\FN{}`

Comment: If you've ever used a decent editor with a replace all (across multiple files if necessary) you could do it in less time than it took to type the question.

Comment: You've missed the point, which I tried to clarify in an edit.  Changing **all** manually, or even with a tool like `perl` is a one-way operation. No way to revert. Redefining the command leaves only the real footnotes to deal with.

Comment: If you want to reply to a comment, you need to include the username of the user you're replying to (e.g. @ChrisH) to reply to me. Now you've said it needs to be reversible that changes things -- I'd use a new command inline that's defined as meaning `\footnote` to avoid the mess of having *foot* mean *end*.  It's still not that clear in the question -- you haven;t used *reversible* or a synonym (and actually a find/replace could easily be reversed so long as you don't map many strings to one)

Comment: References should normally use a citation format rather than endnotes (I often use a numeric superscript style, with alphabetic superscript footnotes -- you need some way to distinguish between the two, after all).  That just leaves your "scholarly notes".  If they always relate to a cited work, here's one way to do it, by [adding text to the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136711/28808) but I think I've seen a more generic way that I can't currently find.

Answer (score 0):

For the context explained above, the following solution works, and more importantly, can be easily reverted to the standard behavior of `\footnote`, while maintaining the distinction visually in the text.

That is, all `\footnote{}`s in the text are changed to numbered endnotes that appear in a final `\chapter*{Notes}` and have numeric superscripts.  All `\FN{}`s appear as footnotes in the text and have alphabetic superscripts.  Assume that the following commands are contained in a file `inputs/endnotes.tex` and included in the main file via `\input{inputs/endnotes}`.

```
\usepackage{pagenote}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\newcommand{\FN}[1]{\oldfootnote{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\makepagenote
\let\footnote\pagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
```

For this to work, the original `\footnote` definition has to be captured first and assigned to `\FN`, and the footnote symbol changed, before changing to `\pagenote`.

This, of course, requires that the **Notes** be printed.  Here, it is printed just after the Bibliography, using

```
\bibliography{timeref,graphics}

% Endnotes
\chapter*{Notes}
\printnotes
...
```

To **revert** to the usual, inline printing of footnotes, but still distinguish those from endnotes, use the following, which prints the **true** footnotes in blue, and just comments out the inclusion of the file that changes the definition of `\footnote` to `\endnote`.

```
\newcommand{\FN}[1]{{\footnote{\color{blue}#1}}}
%\input{inputs/endnotes}
```

and also comment out the lines to print the endnotes

```
% Endnotes
%\chapter*{Notes}
%\printnotes
```